# How to make a definition work using a recursion: a product of $n$ elements in semigroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, recursion

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a semigroup, that is, a set $G$ together with a function $\cdot\colon G\times G \to G$ so that for any $g_1,g_2,g_3 \in g$ we have
$$\cdot(g_1,\cdot(g_2,g_3)) = \cdot(\cdot(g_1,g_2),g_3)$$
where we denote $\cdot(g_1,g_2)$ by $g_1\cdot g_2$.

I want to see how we can define a function $f\colon G^n\to G$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ so that

> - $f(g_1,g_2) = g_1\cdot g_2$,
> - $f(g_1,...,g_n, g_{n+1}) = f(g_1,...,g_n)\cdot g_{n+1}$.

Obviously, a recursion theorem of some form is need to be used here. However, I don't see how we can apply it formally instead of just handwaving away and saying "define by induction".

Comment: Your highlighted bullet points look like a perfectly good definition to me. You could let your base case be $f(g_1)=g_1$ for slightly more generality.

Comment: You might find it easier if you use distinct symbols $f_n : G^n \to G$ for "each $f$", as they are not really the same function.

Comment: You are defining multiple functions. A function $f_n$ for each $n$. Also, From the associative property it follows that $\cdot$ doesn't depend on the order of parentheses - https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Associative_implies_generalized_associative.